# Has Boot Camp changed in Snow Leopard?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

I have a brand new MacBook Pro which I use exclusively in Windows 7.

Is it worth buying Snow Leopard?

Since I don't use Mac OX at all (and don't intend to in the future), I don't need the HFS+ driver.

Does Snow Leopard include any other improvements for Boot Camp?

Also, does anyone know when (whether?) Apple's trackpads will work with Windows 7's multi-touch?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you prefer 7? I've installed 7 using boot camp but found the performance was not great in comparison to Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, @ $29 it's worth buying Snow Leopard, and I can name you two reasons :

1. Full support for Windows 7 (both x32 and x64) with Bootcamp 3.0
2. Improved battery life (probably with the updated drivers)

Are you referring to Windows 7 *touchscreen* multi-touch? In that case, the answer is no, Apple trackpads will not work with Windows 7 multi-touch functions. In fact, I think you are missing out on the whole point of multi-touch here.

Comment: Thanks; I think I will buy it. About the trackpad, I meant gesture multi-touch. I also wish Apple would support more gestures in Windows, such as Forward/Back, Show Desktop, and Flip3D or Alt-Tab, the way they do in Mac OS.